# Subseting dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I would like to get `d3` from `d2` and `d1`. That said, I would lke the keys that d1 and d2 have in common and take the 0th element of `criterion` and the 1st element of `other`, as opposed to the index itself. The result `d3` should contain any left over keys that were not in `d1` as well as the selected values. Thank you.

```
d1 = {'criterion': 0, 'other':1, 'n_estimators': 240}

d2 = {'criterion': ["gini", "entropy", "log_loss"], 'other': ["sqrt", "log2"]}

d3 = {'criterion': "gini", 'other':"entropy", 'n_estimators': 240}
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're asking, but the pattern is ambiguous. Shouldn't `other` yield  `log2` in `d3`?

Comment: Your question is contradicting itself. First you say you only want the keys that the dictionaries have in common, but then you say that the result should contain any left over keys from `d2` that weren't in `d1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over `d1`, getting values from `d2` where available, and keeping the `d1` value otherwise:

```
d3 = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    if k in d2:
        d3[k] = d2[k][v]
    else:
        d3[k] = v
```

A perhaps overly concise version of this can be written as a dictcomp:

```
d3 = {k: d2[k][v] if k in d2 else v for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Comment: Note: I'm assuming the numbers are supposed to be indices in the corresponding value from `d2` when it exists. Your example is slightly off; `'other'` maps to `1`, which should map to `"log2"` in `d2`, while your example produces `"entropy"`. I'm assuming this is just a mistake on your part, but if it's not, you need to clarify the rules for producing the output.

Comment: @Barmar: `d2[k]` gets the `list` associated with `'criterion'` (when `'criterion'` is the iteration variable), since `v` is `0`, `d2[k][v]` gets that 0th element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at what you actually want here, and am providing a suggestion for better design. `d2` is a dictionary that maps a category number to a string, I think. So let's give it a more descriptive name. I assume you will do this for many dicts, so you should make a function to do so.

```
def dictmaker(d_in):
    category_dict = {'criterion': ["gini", "entropy", "log_loss"], 'other': ["sqrt", "log2"]}
    d_new = {}
    for k, v in d_in.items():  # iter thru input dict
        if k in category_dict:  # if key is a category-type key
            v = category_dict[k][v]  # get the category string and set to value
        d_new[k] = v
    return d_new
    
print(dictmaker({'criterion': 0, 'other':1, 'n_estimators': 240}))
```